# Symbol for a laboratory flask

Tags: symbols

Is anybody aware of a `dingbat` symbol resembling something like a conical flask from a laboratory, or alternatively an old-fashioned round-bottomed bottle? I've scanned through the comprehensive symbols list document a couple of times, but haven't found anything.

I could draw one in TikZ, but I'd rather use one that already exists.

Comment: You can try `pst-labo`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're looking for an icon, the fontawesome font has a fa-flask icon, accessible with the fontawesome package through the `\faBeaker` command. Note, as it's an Opentype font, you can use it only with LuaLateX or XeLaTeX.

**New:** Since version `4.4`, `fontawesome` can be used with `(pdf)latex`.

Demo:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond} 
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

This can be used as a labo icon: \color{Cyan2}\enspace \faBeaker

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is a shame that this package seems not to be in the comprehensive symbols list, although maybe that's because of the XeLaTeX restriction.

Comment: Probably. I'd like to make it usable for (pdf)latex users, but there's one difficulty: it has 519 icons, and a traditional font for LaTeX can have at most 256 characters, so it should be split into several fonts, and that's beyong my competence. Anyway, I'm not sure this would be legal.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `pst-labo` Few samples are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
  \psset{unit=0.5cm}
  \psset{tubeCoude=true}
  \rule{0pt}{2.5cm}%
  \begin{pspicture}
    \pstTubeEssais[glassType=erlen]
  \end{pspicture}
  \begin{pspicture}
    \pstTubeEssais[glassType=ballon]
  \end{pspicture}
  \begin{pspicture}
    \pstTubeEssais
  \end{pspicture}
  \psset{tubeDroit=true}
  \rule{0pt}{4cm}%
  \begin{pspicture}
    \pstTubeEssais[glassType=erlen]
  \end{pspicture}
  \begin{pspicture}
    \pstTubeEssais[glassType=ballon]
  \end{pspicture}
  \begin{pspicture}
    \pstTubeEssais
  \end{pspicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Check the manual for more.

Comment: That's interesting but seems to be a lot more complicated and flexible than I require.